# How to ensure that the map is loaded

Tags: angular-google-maps

getGMap() returns an instance of the Map object. If the map is not ready, this function returns undefined. Is there an event or a way which tells that the Map is ready and that calling the getGMap will surely return the Google Map?

Thanks

Yash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `uiGmapIsReady` within your controller - see `IsReady` in [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/IsReady).

`uiGmapIsReady` returns:
- a promise once the map is loaded and ready
- an array of map info (which i've called `map_instances`)
-- the array length depends on how many maps you have loaded in your page
-- each object in the array includes the google map object

To use `getGmap()` ready on your control object would then look like this:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
        center="map.center" 
        zoom="map.zoom" 
        control="map.control">
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, uiGmapIsReady) {

    $scope.map = {
        center : {
            latitude: 37.7749295, 
            longitude: -122.4194155 
        },
        zoom : 14,
        control : {}
    };

    uiGmapIsReady.promise()
    .then(function (map_instances) {
        var map1 = $scope.map.control.getGMap();    // get map object through $scope.map.control getGMap() function
        var map2 = map_instances[0].map;            // get map object through array object returned by uiGmapIsReady promise
    });

});
```

Note how you can also access the map object through two methods:
- via the `map_instances` array (which looks like `[map1Instance, map2Instance,  ...]`)
- via `$scope.map.control.getGMap()` as long as you've defined it in your html and `$scope`

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/1hggj89q/)

Answer (score 1):

You could attach to the tilesloaded event by passing it into the "events" property of the map options. tilesloaded fire after a tile is loaded on the map (therefore the map is loaded).

Comment: Reference for the map events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for.  `$scope.map.control.getGMap()` is undefined if he calls it before google has loaded on the page.  The promise checks that.